# Add additional information for meeting organizer in Outlook

Tags: outlook

We have a special case that we need to implement regarding appointments. When an appointment is created, the same detail is sent to both the organizer and the attendees. We need to add additional information which is only visible to the organizer. Is this possible in the appointment?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CustomProperties of Appointment. Please refer to the following links:

[Create appointment with custom properties in EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377838/create-appointment-with-custom-properties-in-ews)

[Set CustomProperties on appointment for all attendees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216537/set-customproperties-on-appointment-for-all-attendees)